# Registration help for NASM assembler forum

Tags: nasm

The last few weeks I've been trying to register with the NASM assembler forum at forum.nasm.us, but either receive a rejection email or no-response. I've tried using different names, email addresses and IP addresses, but all to no avail. As I can't find any way to contact the site, but have seen the same user names being used here on Stackoverflow, I wondered if a dual member might be able to help me.

I also tried replying to their auto responder email.

Tim

Comment: You can try sending a mail to nasm-users@nasm.us

Comment: Thank you ecm, I've given it a go. Looking at some recent posts might point to it being just an inconvenient time. Tim